# periodic read from iPhone stderr

Tags: iphone, c, stderr, nslog

I'm working on a class that I will use for my own debugging purposes.  I intend it to be an on device version of the debugger console.  Mostly I care about capturing NSLog() statements.
No matter what I log to the console, I'm only getting 0xFF from `fgetc()`.  What I expect to see from `fgetc()` is a character that was sent to stderr since the last call to `update`.  Below is a subclass of UITextView:

`stdErrFP` is defined in the header as: `FILE* stdErrFP;`

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
       stdErrFP = fdopen (fileno (stderr) , "w");
       if (!stdErrFP)
           NSLog(@"errno - %s", strerror(errno));
  
       [self update];
       [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(makeSomeNoise) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
       [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(update) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) update{
 char errBuff[2] = {0x00, '\0'};
 do{
  errBuff[0] = fgetc(stdErrFP);
  self.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.text,  [NSString stringWithCString:errBuff]];
 }while (errBuff[0] != EOF); 
}

-(void) makeSomeNoise{
 CFShow([NSString stringWithString:@"noisy CFFunction"]);
 NSLog(@"noisy NSLog");
 char message[] = "noisy fprintf";
 fprintf(stderr, message);
}
```

`-(void)makeSomeNoise` has so many different log types, because [Eric Sadun wrote that NSLog doesn't log to stderr](http://blogs.oreilly.com/digitalmedia/2007/12/redirecting-log-data-on-the-ip.html), so i wanted to rule that out as a possibility.  I'm not sure if this is related to my problem, but I noticed that `fdopen()` always fails unless the flag is "w", this can't be right.

UPDATE:  for `fdopen()` I was wrong, it's not that only "w" works, it's that only "r" DOESN'T work.  (i.e. both "a" and "w" work).  The errno when I use "r" is: `No such file or directory`.  So it looks like I'm not properly connecting to stderr.  StackOverflow Genius, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best I can code, you can not read from stderr.   The stderr buffer is like a firehose, trying to grab anything meaningful is very time dependent.